# Having trouble with Playpen error

Tags: c++

I am doing C++ tutorials, just trying to learn it. I am running into a problem. one of the tutorials used playpen.h, but it doesn't compile, the following error occurs:

```
playpen.h' file not found

    #include "playpen.h"

         ^
1 error generated.
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the playpen.h is and how to get it?

Comment: [First response on google for "playpen.h"](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/34461/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the name of that "tutorial" *You Can Program in C++* by Francis Glassborow? If so, the playpen library is supposed to come with the CD included in the book. If you don't have it, the publisher seems to offer the material for download:

http://www.wiley.com/legacy/wileychi/glassborowc++/material.html